# Dynamic Form Submit URL

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a drop-down form on a landing page that needs to change the Submit button URL upon form submission. See screen shot below:

[Drop Down Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/347r9.png)

Here is the code for the form:

```
<form action="/fsg?pageId=fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef32&amp;variant=a" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="pageId" value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef32">
    <input type="hidden" name="pageVariant" value="a">
    <fieldset class="clearfix" style="width: 483px; height: -21px;">
    <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_which_best_describes_your_company">
    <select id="which_best_describes_your_company" name="which_best_describes_your_company" class="text form_elem_which_best_describes_your_company">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="Tire Dealer">Tire Dealer</option>
        <option value="Auto Service Dealer">Auto Service Dealer</option>
        <option value="Tire Wholesaler">Tire Wholesaler</option>
        <option value="Auto Parts Shop">Auto Parts Shop</option>
        <option value="Warehouse Distributor">Warehouse Distributor</option>
        <option value="Jobber">Jobber</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
     </select>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've found a few codes that seem like they could work, but I'm not experienced enough to a) alter the code for a dropdown menu and b) add more than one or two URLs (there are six or so options). Can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance :)

**ETA:** I'm not actually able to edit the form code, as it's drag-and-drop in my editor.

Comment: do you want to submit form depending on selected option from dropdown list?

Comment: Yup! Correct. The form submit should redirect them to the appropriate landing page for their selection.

Comment: For accurate help I need you to show dropdown list values and those six url address with specified relation between dropdown list values and urls

Comment: Sure! They should be mapped as follows:

Tire Dealer: http://www.mamsoftware.com/usa/vast-enterprise-retail
Auto Service Dealer: http://www.mamsoftware.com/usa/vast-enterprise-retail
Tire Wholesaler: http://www.mamsoftware.com/usa/vast-enterprise-wholesale
Auto Parts Shop: http://www.mamsoftware.com/usa/autopart
Warehouse Distributor: http://www.mamsoftware.com/usa/autopart
Jobber: http://www.mamsoftware.com/usa/autopart
Other: http://www.mamsoftware.com/usa/e-mail

Please let me know if you need more info!

Comment: 1) Do you plan to change the "pageId" param in url and in <input type="hidden"> element for each selected option ? If so, than you need to have predefined list of those page ids beforehand. 2) What are you using now: native Javascript or JQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

Use a listener on the select element to capture the selected value and append or use it to modify the form action. The following example appends the selected value to the form action:

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="/fsg?pageId=fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef32&amp;variant=a" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="pageId" value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef32"><input type="hidden" name="pageVariant" value="a">
    <fieldset class="clearfix" style="width: 483px; height: -21px;">
    <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_which_best_describes_your_company">
    <select onchange="updateFormAction()" id="which_best_describes_your_company" name="which_best_describes_your_company" class="text form_elem_which_best_describes_your_company"><option value="">Select One</option><option value="Tire Dealer">Tire Dealer</option><option value="Auto Service Dealer">Auto Service Dealer</option><option value="Tire Wholesaler">Tire Wholesaler</option><option value="Auto Parts Shop">Auto Parts Shop</option><option value="Warehouse Distributor">Warehouse Distributor</option><option value="Jobber">Jobber</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function updateFormAction() {
 var selectedVal = document.getElementById('which_best_describes_your_company').value
 var form = document.getElementById('form')
 form.setAttribute('action', form.action + '&company='+selectedVal)
}
```

Here is the fiddle to test it : https://jsfiddle.net/h23g6o3x/

Comment: Thanks! This might be a dumb question, but where in the script would I update the URL per option? Would I create a separate "alert" for each URL?

Comment: The alert is just to show that the form action is modified. It's not necessary. I have updated the answer. To answer your question, you should update line 4 in the above script. I would recommend you learn the basics of javascript, especially [setAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) and [event listeners](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code, the pageId is the important information. So I would put this as the value of your dropdown (below is just dummy data, needs to be replaced with actual pageIds) and set the value in the onchange method.

```
<form action="/fsg?pageId=fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef32&amp;variant=a" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="pageId" value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef32">

    <input type="hidden" name="pageVariant" value="a">

    <fieldset class="clearfix" style="width: 483px; height: -21px;">

        <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_which_best_describes_your_company">

            <select id="which_best_describes_your_company" name="which_best_describes_your_company"
                    class="text form_elem_which_best_describes_your_company" onchange="selectionChanged(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef32">Tire Dealer</option>
                <option value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef33">Auto Service Dealer</option>
                <option value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef34">Tire Wholesaler</option>
                <option value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef35>Auto Parts Shop</option>
                <option value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef36">Warehouse Distributor</option>
                <option value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef37">Jobber</option>
                <option value="fbfa157c-2f78-4150-b3c7-fc1ca4cbef38">Other</option>
            </select>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
    function(selectedPageId){
         document.getElementById('pageId).value = selectedPageId
     }
</script>
```